# tvOS UINavigationController fades out bottom margin of UITableViewController

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, tvos

[image: Left: Contained in UINavigationViewController]

In the screenshot, I have the same UITableViewController (filled in with static cells with purple background color) in two different configurations.

The left one is contained inside UINavigationController.
The right one is not contained.
(Both are inside UITabBarController.)

Notice that there is large space at the bottom on the left one. What's causing this and how can I prevent it from happening?

I put up an example project on GitHub: https://github.com/barumrho/tvosnavigationcontroller

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.. You need to set UIViewControllers "automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets" to FALSE and hide UINavigationControllers "navigationBar"

```
    navController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
    navController?.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```